# Next Auth Cannot Sign In With Google - Prisma Adapter

Tags: prisma, next.js13, next-auth

> I try to sign in with google using next auth and it works fine, but when i add the prisma adapter to my route file i get an error `Try signing in with a different account.` And in the terminal i can see this
> Invalid `prisma.account.findUnique()` invocation:
> Operation 'findUnique' for model 'Account' does not match any query.
> i am using mysql
> This is my route file

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import prisma from "@/prisma/client";

const handler = NextAuth({
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

This is my prisma schema

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Issue {
  id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  title       String   @db.VarChar(255)
  description String   @db.Text
  status      Status   @default(OPEN)
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime @updatedAt
}

enum Status {
  OPEN
  IN_PROGRESS
  CLOSED
}

model Account {
  id                 String  @id @default(cuid())
  userId             String
  type               String
  provider           String
  providerAccountId  String
  refresh_token      String?  @db.Text
  access_token       String?  @db.Text
  expires_at         Int?
  token_type         String?
  scope              String?
  id_token           String?  @db.Text
  session_state      String?

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
}

model Session {
  id           String   @id @default(cuid())
  sessionToken String   @unique
  userId       String
  expires      DateTime
  user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}

model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
}

model VerificationToken {
  identifier String
  token      String   @unique
  expires    DateTime

  @@unique([identifier, token])
}
```

This is my prisma client

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prismaClientSingleton = () => {
  return new PrismaClient();
};

type PrismaClientSingleton = ReturnType<typeof prismaClientSingleton>;

const globalForPrisma = globalThis as unknown as {
  prisma: PrismaClientSingleton | undefined;
};

const prisma = globalForPrisma.prisma ?? prismaClientSingleton();

export default prisma;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") globalForPrisma.prisma = prisma;
```

I tried to sign in with google and i got redirected to `/api/auth/signin?error=Callback` with a **Try signing in with a different account** message. I expected to be signed in and for next auth to store that information in my database